# Powershell, WPF, Dragablz - Unable to ascertain tab control

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm attempting to create a simple WPF window from Powershell with a Dragablz tab control, but when I attempt to tear out a tab item from the window, I receive the following error:

```
Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to ascertain tab control."
At C:\Users\user\Downloads\dragablz_xaml.ps1:26 char:1
+ $form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ApplicationException
```

I assume this has something to do with the DefaultInterTabClient, but I'm having difficulty tracking down why or how to get around it.

The following is my sample code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -Path .\Dragablz.dll

$xaml = @'
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"
        Title="Dragablz" 
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <dragablz:TabablzControl Margin="8" x:Name="tabcontrol">
        <dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
            <dragablz:InterTabController />
        </dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
        <TabItem Header="Tab No. 1" IsSelected="True">
            <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab No. 2">
            <TextBlock>We Have Tearable Tabs!</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
    </dragablz:TabablzControl>   
</Window>
'@

$form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($xaml)

$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```